# CSS background-image: url path

Tags: css, background-image

If I am running my web project locally from a local directory and linking to background image files in CSS, it seems only ../ method works, if i put / instead of ../ then it doesnt work. But if I run it on a web server then I can just put a forward-slash in the beginning to make the path look from the root of the web-site. This is what I am trying to achieve but wondering if this is normal?

Comment: Looks like in your local, you are not running in a server, but a file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior since in the file system, you have open the css, or the css has to make reference from where it stands, in this case, it has to go back its own file name to search for the image. 
In the server this is already acknowledge so it doesn't have to "go back".